# BizTalk 2013 R2 CPU consumption very high

Tags: performance, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

We migrated an application from BizTalk 2009 to 2013 R2 , after that it is noticed the  one host which is assigned to orchestration take very high CPU usage some it goes up to 100%, the application is same as in 2009 no changes done.

Is there any way we control this?

Appplication is used mostly for HL7 message processsing

Answer (score 1):

High CPU usage, even 100%, is not necessarily a problem unless it's continuous and there is no legitimate reason for it to happen.

Think of it this way, you paid for the processors, might as well use them.

So, is this causing an actual problem or is it just an observation?  Also important, are you sure the old setup did not have the same behavior?

Comment: Yes the 100% CPU some time remains for more than 5 minutes , causing a process monitoring program to raise an alert